# How to start an Activity from ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I made a ListView, and a StringArray. It show's OK, but I don't know how to start Activity from this list. I want to start on Activity when I click an item. Start another Activity, when click an another item...

Here is,

**The String Array:**

```
 <array name="List">
        <item name="samu">Samsung</item>
        <item>Htc</item>
        <item>Sony</item>
        <item>Huwai</item>
    </array>
```

**The List_Layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.zokni1996.android_forum.List">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:entries="@array/List" />
```

And the Java (the fixed the imports, just don't past here):

```
public class List extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

       ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    } }
```

Comment: Make a listener like list.setonitemclickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){}

Comment: Here is a tutorial exactly matching to your requirment http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-creating-and-populating-listview-items-in-xml/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add onItemClickListener to your listView, then start activity based on the clicked item. for example,

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener){
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
           String selected = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
           if(selected.equals("htc") {
               //start htc activity
           }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
          // intent
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });
```